# automatic update jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jtextfield, event-dispatch-thread

Does anyone know how to update a jTextfield every 5 secondes? Automatic. So no userinput is required. It is used to update time in a textfield. This is what i tried but then my program freezes.

```
while(true){
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        txtCheck.setText(convert.getCheck());
                        System.out.println("Ja");
                        }
```

convert is a thread, i tried to throw an exception but failed, cause Eclise says Threads can't throw exceptions.

Convert.getCheck:

```
    public String getCheck() {
        return check;
    }
```

Comment: Where is this while loop you are showing?  In main(), in a JFrame, in a JPanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a Swing Timer object. Here is a [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

To start with, you need to have your class implement the ActionListener interface. Inside of your class, you also need to implement an actionPerformed() method. Finally, you should start the timer in your main() function or somewhere

```
timer = new Timer(5000, MyClass);
timer.setInitialDelay(pause);
timer.start();
```

You would then implement your class like:

```
public class MyClass implements ActionListener
{
   ...

   void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       /*
        This is called every time the timer fires, put your code here
       */
   }
 }
```